# javascript get x and y coordinates on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseclick

I have a little div tag that when I click on it (`onClick` event), it will run the `printMousePos()` function.

These are the `HTML` tags:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <!-- By the way, this is not the actual html file, just a generic example. -->
        <script src='game.js'></script>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="example">
            <p id="test">x: , y:</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the `printMousePos` function in a seperate .js file:

```
function printMousePos() {
    var cursorX;
    var cursorY;
    document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
}
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "x: " + cursorX + ", y: " + cursorY;
}
```

Yes, the function actually works (it knows when you click it and all), but it returns `undefined` for both `x` and `y`, so I'm assuming that the getting `x` and `y` logic in the function is incorrect. Any Ideas? I also know there aren't any built-in functions within javascript itself to return the `x` and `y` like in java, ex. would there be a way to do it with say JQuery or PHP? (avoid those if possible though, javascript would be best). Thanks!

Comment: `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`

Comment: @Jonathan I tried that, still returns undefined though.

Comment: CursorX and cursorY are undefined before the mouse move event is triggered. If you want the position from the click event pass event to the printMousePos function

Comment: Using **event.clientX and **event.clientY** provides the coordinates relative to the element taking into account margin, padding and border measures.

To get the right coordinates, use **event.offsetX** and **event.offsetY**.

Answer (score 146):

Like this.

```js
function printMousePos(event) {
  document.body.textContent =
    "clientX: " + event.clientX +
    " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

**[MouseEvent - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)**

> MouseEvent.clientX <kbd>Read only</kbd>
>   The X coordinate of the mouse pointer in local (DOM content) coordinates.
>
> MouseEvent.clientY <kbd>Read only</kbd>
>   The Y coordinate of the mouse pointer in local (DOM content) coordinates.

Comment: Re: [pageX/Y vs. clientX/Y](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1869-jquery-mouse-events-pagex-y-vs-clientx-y.htm)

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as so

Comment: doesnt work if click was inside an iframe

Answer (score 17):

**It sounds like your** `printMousePos` **function should:**

1. Get the X and Y coordinates of the mouse
2. Add those values to the HTML

**Currently, it does these things:**

1. Creates (undefined) variables for the X and Y coordinates of the mouse
2. Attaches a function to the "mousemove" event (which will set those variables to the mouse coordinates when triggered by a mouse move)
3. Adds the current values of your variables to the HTML

***See the problem?***

Your variables are never getting set, because as soon as you add your function to the "mousemove" event you print them.

It seems like you probably don't need that mousemove event at all; I would try something like this:

```
function printMousePos(e) {
    var cursorX = e.pageX;
    var cursorY = e.pageY;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "x: " + cursorX + ", y: " + cursorY;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

simple solution is this:

game.js:

```
document.addEventListener('click', printMousePos, true);
function printMousePos(e){
  
      let cursorX = e.pageX;
      let cursorY= e.pageY;
      $( "#test" ).text( "pageX: " + cursorX +",pageY: " + cursorY );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### 3 ways to get mouse positions:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  // evt.clientX/Y: position relative to VIEWPORT
  // evt.screenX/Y: position relative to SCREEN
  // evt.pageX/Y  : position relative to PAGE (different from viewport
  // if the page is scrolled)
})
```

---

Please **click the run button** in the snippet above to see mouse position printed in real time:

```js
const updateView = (e = {}) =>  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = `
  <div>
    Relative to screen:<br>
    e.screenX: <b>${e.screenX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.screenY: <b>${e.screenY || '0'}</b>
  </div>
  <div>
    Relative to viewport:<br>
    e.clientX: <b>${e.clientX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.clientY: <b>${e.clientY || '0'}</b>
  </div> 
  <div>
    Relative to page (scroll to see the difference with viewport):<br>
    e.pageX: <b>${e.pageX || '0'}</b><br>
    e.pageY: <b>${e.pageY || '0'}</b>
  </div>
`

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `BIG CONTENT `.repeat(300)

document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateView)

updateView()
```

```css
#log { display:flex;justify-content:center;position:fixed }
#log > div { flex: 1 1 0 }
```

```html
<div id='log'></div>
<div id='content' style='opacity:.1'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
const txt = document.getElementById('test');
const div = document.getElementById('example');

function printMousePos(event) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY;
    txt.innerHTML = `x: ${mouseX}, y: ${mouseY}`
}

div.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

I know that this is an old post from 9 years ago but I wanted to give a response for anyone having issues.