# How to make anywhere in the page clickable then see what css precent in the page they clicked

Tags: javascript

I need to give a area on the page where anywhere in that area the user can click. When the user clicks, I want to import where they clicked on the page into a javascript variable. For example, if they clicked in the center of the page I want the javascript variable to be "50% 50%" If they clicked on the left corner of the page it would be "0% 0%" and so on. How would I do this? And Please only Javascript and html and css. No JQuery

Comment: You need to search for words "javascript click coordinates". Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744605/javascript-get-x-and-y-coordinates-on-mouse-click

Answer (score 2):

This code should be a good enough place for you to start...

See it in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/22rx6wp5/

```
var clickArea = document.getElementById ('click-area');
var percents = document.getElementById ('percents');
var clickRect = clickArea.getBoundingClientRect ();
var x, y, xp, yp, percentages;

// Click function
clickArea.onclick = function (event) {
    var cx, cy;

    // Get click position
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
        cx = event.clientX;
        cy = event.clientY;
    } else {
        cx = event.pageX;
        cy = event.pageY;
    }

    // Relate position to element position on page
    x = cx - this.offsetLeft;
    y = cy - this.offsetTop;

    // Calculate position in percentage
    xp = Math.round ((x / clickRect.width) * 100);
    yp = Math.round ((y / clickRect.height) * 100);

    // Percentages text
    percentages = xp + '% ' + yp + '%';

    // Display percentages in percents span
    percents.textContent = percentages;

    // Display percentages in browser console
    console.log (percentages);
};
```