# HTML5 File: How to log output to a local Text or CSV-file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, logging

For a school homework I've created an html5 file.  I am trying to track mouse position on that file. The code for the mouse position is taken from here: [javascript get x and y coordinates on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744605/javascript-get-x-and-y-coordinates-on-mouse-click). I would like to log output data onto a text file or a csv file on my computer instead of printing them out. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, HTML is not allowed to write files on the computer running it. Your options are to log in a localStorage, or in memory and put on the page a link to export this memory as a downloadable file. Then you click the link and let your browser save it.